# How to send a Dictionary<string,Model> via ajax to controller in ASP MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here's the test action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testButton(MultiEventViewModel multiEventModel, Dictionary<String,Gift> giftList){
    return Json("success"); 
}
```

Gift Model

```
public class Gift {
    public string ASIN;
    public string title;
    public string imgSource;
    public string link;
    public int count;
}
```

The submit button, the dictionary and how its populated:

```
_validation.isExists = function (obj) {
    return (((typeof obj) == 'undefined') || (obj === null)) ? false : true;
}
var giftList = {};
// Theres a list view with bunches of items from amazon, each item has an add button. 
// Each button's onclick will add that item's metadata to giftList. Here's how it being added. 
$(".addGift-primary").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var title = grandParent.children(".hiddenTitle").html();
        var imgSource = grandParent.children("img").attr("src");
        var link = grandParent.find("a").attr("href");
        var ASIN = grandParent.attr("id");
        if (_validation.isExists(giftList[ASIN])) 
            giftList[ASIN].count += 1;
        else {
            giftList[ASIN] = {
                "ASIN": ASIN, "title": title,
                "imgSource": imgSource, "link": link, count: 1
            };
        }
        popupDialog("addGiftSuccessDialog")
    });
});

$("#addCustomGiftButton").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testButton',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { multiEventModel: $("#createEventForm").serializeObject(), giftList: giftList },
        success: function (e) {
            console.log("success ");
        }
    });
});
```

What happened is that when I debug, for each key-value pair, only the key is passed (I used ASIN as key), the value is an instance of Gift with all null attributes (here's the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGQJy.png)

Is there any other way I can fix/work around this?

Items (gifts) are added dynamically to the list of gifts, so beside Dictionary I'm not sure what else to use in the controller?

Comment: In your `Gift` class you used fields, but the default model-binder would only bind propertied.

Comment: @haim770 Could you elaborate? Im not sure I understand

Comment: In your `Gift` class, change the fields to properties and you should be fine

Comment: @haim770 let me try that again. Cause earlier I was actually using property (ex public string ASIN {get;set;}) but it yielded the same result

Comment: @haim770: still didnt work :( .... (I changed to {get;set;} for each attribute of the class). Should I read up on writing a custom model binder or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, by converting object/Dictionary to array/List before sending:

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testButton(MultiEventViewModel multiEventModel, List<Gift> giftList){
    return Json("success"); 
}
```

Client:

```
var dictToList = function (obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var result =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) result.push(obj[keys[i]]);
    return result
}
...
$("#addCustomGiftButton").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testButton',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { multiEventModel: $("#createEventForm").serializeObject(), giftList: dictToList(giftList) },
        success: function (e) {
            console.log("success ");
        }
    });
});
```

Even though this didn't really answer my question, but it did the work and my actual problem was solved. If anyone has any other solution, please let me know. (I haven't tested my solution for more complex Model, so it might work just for now)